# Can't extend desktop to second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, intel-graphics, monitor, mate

I have a Vostro 200, Intel Pentium D (E2160) processor and Intel G31/G33 video adapter.  The video adapter is integrated and I'm using a VGA splitter to connect to monitors.  The monitors are Samsung 19" widescreen Syncmasters.  I have Ubuntu 13.04 installed, running the MATE desktop environment.  Both monitors are working, but the second one is cloning the first one.  It won't let me extend the desktop.  When I open the Monitor Preferences screen and click on the Detect Monitors button, it doesn't do anything.  It only detects one monitor.  Does anyone have any ideas of what I can try to get the desktop extended to the second monitor, instead of cloned?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "Y" VGA splitter will always mirror the image. From this nice explained [article](http://www.phinesolutions.com/new-dell-desktop-get-a-dual-monitor.html), you need a low profile card with a [DMS (dual monitor solution) port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59), plugged to a DMS splitter cable.